# Initialize vector with function in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, vectorization

just started out with matlab and have some troubles finding the solution for the following action:

I am trying to initialize a vector of 1000 **different** values, with a function that doesn't take any arguments as input. I can do this with a for loop, but haven't found out how to do it without.

What I expected that would work:

```
z = zeros(1,1000)
result = arrayfun(*functionname*,z)
```

This however gives an error saying that the first input must be a function handle.

My function is a simple implementation of a monte carlo method to calculate pi:

```
   function Result = mcm()                                                                                                                                                                        
   clear                                                                           
   N=1000;                                                                         
   M=0;                                                                            
   for j=1:N                                                                       
           p=[2*rand-1; 2*rand-1];                                                 
           if p'*p<1                                                               
           M=M+1;                                                                  
          end                                                                     
   end                                                                             
   Result=4*M/N
```

Comment: Do you want the same value everywhere?  If so then use `z = ones(1,1000) * mcm;`

Comment: In this case, I think that a loop is the most appropriate way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to *actually* vectorize your given function `mcm` would be -

```
N = 1000; %// Number of data points 
P = [2*rand(1,N)-1; 2*rand(1,N)-1]; %// OR 2*rand(2,N)-1
out = 4*sum(sum(P.^2,1)<1)/N
```

**Runtime tests**

Code -

```
N = 1000000; %// Number of data points 

disp('---------------- With Original Approach')
tic
M=0;
for j=1:N
    P=[2*rand-1; 2*rand-1];
    if P'*P<1
        M=M+1;
    end
end
Result=4*M/N;
toc

disp('---------------- With Proposed Approach')
tic
P = 2*rand(2,N)-1;
out = 4*sum(sum(P.^2,1)<1)/N;
toc
```

Timings & Outputs -

```
---------------- With Original Approach
Elapsed time is 3.952998 seconds.
---------------- With Proposed Approach
Elapsed time is 0.089590 seconds.
>> Result
Result =
       3.1422
>> out
out =
       3.1428
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your function takes no arguments you can't use `arrayfun`.  `arrayfun` applies the function to each element in the array.

Instead use this:

```
z = ones(1,1000) * mcm;
```

A side benefit is that `mcm` will only run once so it will be faster than looping that function 1000 times.

Comment: I imagine the OP wants different numbers each time to do some statistical analyses on like finding the standard errors etc...

Comment: In this case it isn't convenient because I want to get 1000 different calculations of the function.

Comment: @AlfonsIngomar then you need to change your question.  This answer does exactly what your question asks.  It initializes a vector with a function value.  To make it do what you want, put a dummy input in `mcm` and don't use it.  Then you can use `arrayfun`.  Or simply use a for loop.